# Assign attributes to Prefix Property in ListS3 Processor

Tags: apache-nifi, prefix

i need to ingest based on curent month and previous month and if we didn't get files for previous month i need to again run the listS3 processor for previous month based on current month. i have to manually change the month and then get the files instead i have a thought of assigning the previous month attribute based on current month to the ListS3 processor Prefix property. i need a help.

i have tried to fetch all files and then routing them based on month and again routing them based on year and so on. so if we can assign the attributes to ListS3 processor then it could be easy to fetch the files previous month based on current month.